Flutter youtube_player plugin trying to access camera
I used the below plugin from a verified flutter developer from official flutter page
https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter
Surprisingly, this plugin is trying to access the camera, which I confirmed by looking at the error stactrace (below)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: getCameraCharacteristics:851: Unable to retrieve camera characteristics for unknown device 0: No such file or directory (-2)

Is this a bug (!!) ,like a platform problem ? ( Remember when android released a newer version, all old applications by default asking every single permissions) or is this plugin suspicious.
The issue has been reported multiple times in his github page but there aint a word from the developer
Issue 1
Issue 2
Issue 3
